# Android: How to enable button when service complete its task?

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, android-service

I have two buttons **StartButton** and **StopButton** on MainActivity.java . When I press **StartButton** a **Service** is created and StartButton get **disable**. On pressing **StopButton** Service get destroyed and StartButton get **enable**.

What I wanted to do is to **enable** my Start Button as Service completed its task; it **returns any notification or trigger type event or message value** on my MainActivity.java so my Start Button get enable.

Please give me any idea, concept or code to make it easy for me to understand.

Comment: are you using IntentService ?

Comment: I usually use BroadcastReceiver in this type of situation. Take a look at this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

```
MyButton.setClickable(false);
```

It will make the button disabled.

and

```
MyButton.setClickable(true);
```

It will enable the button.

However, if you want to hide or show the button, you can use,

`MyButton.setVisibiity(VIEW.VISIBLE);` and `MyButton.setVisibiity(VIEW.INVISIBLE);`

**Edit-** As you want to enable the button, once its task is completed, you could open the mainActivity with a flag value true, something like this,

```
Intent i= new Intent(getBaseContext(), myActivity.class);
i.putExtra("flag", true);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(i);
```

and in the **mainActivity**, check the value of flag,

```
Boolean flag;
flag = this.getIntent().getBooleanExtra("flag", false);
if(flag == true) {
MyButton.setClickable(true);
}
```

But for it, you should keep the value of flag initially to `false`.

and once you click the button, you could then set it as not clickable.

Comment: @downvoter: I would love to hear the problem with this answer, so I can improve it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure **ZUBAir hashmi** already knows how to enable/disable the button. The question was how it can be done from the `Service`

Comment: @vmironov I have edited the answer to add some meaning to it.

Comment: ok. but it's really bad idea to start new activity instead of updating the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the communication between service and application take a look at the examples in the [android developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). 
You can enable and disable your buttons in the onServiceDisconnected() and onServiceConnected() methods.

Keep in mind that the service runs in the same thread as your app by default.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to achieve this. Let me tell you one with Broadcast Receiver. I hope you are aware of BroadcastReceiver Concepts.

Changes requires in your activity

1) Create a Broadcast receiver as inner class in your activity.

2) Register it with some action, suppose "MY_ACTION".(remember to unregister this receiver on onPause/onDestroy methods)

3) Suppose service completed its task, and you are into onReceive method of Broadcast receiver, now write your code to enable/disable button(i hope you know how to do it)

Changes requires in your Service

1) find out code where you think its task has completed.

2) Create an intent with same action ("MY_ACTION").

3) Broadcast message with sendBroadcast , intent as param. and you are done. :)

let me know if in any point you feel you are stuck ,